# How to make Excel VBA to ignore formula cells with if condition

Tags: vba, excel

I want to use `if` condition to perform `ClearContents` task. Please find my below code for the same. I written below 2 code's, but both are unsuccessful.

1. First Try

   ```
   t = 1
   Do While Cells(t, 1) <> ""
       If Cells(t, 1) <> "=" Then
           Cells(t, 1).ClearContents
       End If
       t = t + 1
   Loop
   ```
2. Second Try

   ```
   t = 1
   Do While Cells(t, 1) <> ""
       If Cells(t, 1) <> Formula Then
           Cells(t, 1).ClearContents
       End If
       t = t + 1
   Loop
   ```

Basically, I don't want to delete the cells contain where formulas are available but I want to delete the other data.

Comment: You can select all the non-formula cells. Give me a minute.

Comment: Are you trying to empty only column A or do you need the entire worksheet to be cleared of constant values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write something like this:

```
If Not Cells(t,1).HasFormula Then

End if
```

It would work. Or try like this:

```
Sub TestMe()

    If Not Cells(1, 1).HasFormula Then
        Debug.Print "No Formula"
    Else
        Debug.Print "Has Formula"
    End If

End Sub
```

Here is more info about the `.HasFormula` property:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837123.aspx

Comment: getting this error- **Invalid or unqualified reference** for **.HasFormula**

Comment: @sagar - you are probably not assigning value to the `t`. Check it again with the `TestMe` :)

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative, there is a method to select all the cells containing constant (non-formula) values.

```
Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23).ClearContents
```

Faster than iterating all the cells.

Or to do this only on a specific range or the current selection, replace `Cells` with `Range("A1:A100")` or `Selection`.

(In Excel, you can find this under Home -> Editing -> Find & Select -> Go to Special. Here you can have Excel automatically select only the Constants or the Formulas inside the existing selection.)